# Separate items in a variable with commas

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
food = ["pizza", "tacos", "lasagna", "watermelon", "cookies"]
plate = ""
for dish in food:
    print(dish)
    fav_dish = input("Is this your favorite dish? Y/N: ")
    if fav_dish == "Y" and food[-1]:
        plate += dish
    elif fav_dish == "Y":
        plate += dish + ", "
print("I want " + plate +"!")
```

I am practicing my coding skills and I want the results to look like this.

```
I want pizza, tacos, and cake!
```

The results look like this:

```
pizza
Is this your favorite dish? Y/N: Y
tacos
Is this your favorite dish? Y/N: Y
lasagna
Is this your favorite dish? Y/N: N
watermelon
Is this your favorite dish? Y/N: N
cookies
Is this your favorite dish? Y/N: Y
I want pizzatacoscookies!
```

Comment: Make `plate` a list instead of a string, then `", ".join(plate)` will work.

Comment: `if fav_dish == "Y" and food[-1]:` What is the point of that `and` condition?  `food[-1]` is the last item in food, which is "cookies", which is a non-empty string, and so it is always true.

Comment: John Gordon's comment described the problem.  A correction would be to use:  `if fav_dish == "Y" and dish == food[-1]:`,  You will also need: `plate += "and " + dish`

Answer (score 0):

Make `plate` a list, and append to it in the loop. In the end, you can use the following, which will output the correct commas and words:

```
", ".join(plate)
```

Comment: This won't use `and` where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the variable plate as a list where you put the favorite dishes and then use the "".join() function.

You put in the commas the separator you want, and in the parenthesis the list to join. In your case:

```
print("I want " + ", ".join(plate) + "!")
```

Answer (score 0):

first make a list of selection, then operate on that list. This code ignores the case of an empty selection list and can be left as an exercise.

```py
selected = []
for dish in food: 
    select = input(f'Is [{dish}] your favorite dish? Y/N: ')
    if select == 'Y':
        selected.append(dish)
    # since the second option ignores the dish, you can dis include it from the list
if len(selected) > 1:  # do I need the word and at the end of the list
    selected[-1] = f'and {selected[-1]}'
separator = ', '  # define pattern for joining a list
print('I want ', separator.join(selected), '!', sep='') # the `sep` keyword (normally a space) is printed between words
```

Comment: 4a. I use an f-string to embed expressions in literal strings; I can use curly brackets to embed variables into the text.
5. I create the "if" statement and if the "if" statement is true I will append the dish variable into my selected variable. 
6. I like the advice you gave to not create unnecessary code
7. Now, we are addressing the variables inside of the variable I want with an "if" statement. I see you used the separated parameter in the print function to separate the items in the selected variable and the last item in the selected variable will take on a different string.

Comment: How did you connect the two strings in the print function? Honestly, I am slightly confused about the logic behind "len(selected) > 1:".

Comment: I had explanations 1-4, but some of my explanations got deleted. I was trying to make sure I understood your method so I can learn.

Comment: the if statement is used to determine if "and" should be added as a prefix to the last plate selection

The collapse of string could be thought of as a "join" of a list by a variable.
```
seperator = ', '
seperator.join(selected)
```